# Calculate road distance between GPS points

Tags: postgis, postgresql, gps, distance, geolocation

I am working on tracking system that track location of vehicles on the map and tell their total distance from the beginning till today.

I have `device_id`, `timestamp` and `GPS location` in the table like this:

---

```
30 | 2015-09-08 14:16:34 | 0101000020E610000052CD51EC0D733A4080F7E9D3852F5040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:17:01 | 0101000020E6100000C323963902513A40988FFF5D7A315040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:17:15 | 0101000020E6100000046B4194D4383A40633CEF6B49325040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:19:14 | 0101000020E61000006CE7A0F07E213A40279E584C91325040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:19:26 | 0101000020E6100000C7C1001D410B3A40BF4B040539335040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:20:23 | 0101000020E6100000728C648F50EF3940613B736AC2345040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:20:44 | 0101000020E61000002BE1647671E439405EDFE23CF7365040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:20:58 | 0101000020E61000005399BDC7F4D33940033FAA61BF385040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:21:10 | 0101000020E6100000E38FFD874FC33940830FCAA07F3A5040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:21:23 | 0101000020E6100000904C874ECF9D3940800640811C3E5040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:22:01 | 0101000020E61000003AAA3F67778B394044BD851A2A3F5040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:22:14 | 0101000020E610000084C1903067833940B349D97D223F5040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:22:26 | 0101000020E6100000E2B5A6D48078394013697638153F5040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:24:30 | 0101000020E6100000BE1D9727C6E94140404BFCF61A3F5040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:25:07 | 0101000020E6100000C3F92F6BBD78394081C75CBE1A3F5040
30 | 2015-09-08 14:26:39 | 0101000020E6100000F3B116FABB783940522CB7B41A3F5040
```

---

Now I need to calculate progressive road distance between GPS coordinates and save into 4th column called `dist`. Also, I think if it's better to calculate distance right when we receive new GPS location and compare it with previous location and save the calculated distance into `dist` column.

I am quite a newbie in PostgreSQL. I am not sure which approach I should follow, either earthdistance point-based or ST_Distance or is there something more appropriate that can fulfill my requirement?

**Update:**

After some research I found neither earth distance nor ST_Distance gives distance of road network. Is there any way to calculate road distance between GPS coordinates?

Comment: You should show the columns as text, not an image, otherwise nobody can actually use the data as a sample for tests.

Comment: click for [blog]: http://roaddistance.in/ "Road Distance Between Two Places"

Answer (score 4):

So your GPS coordinates are far apart? If they are close - eg. short segments along a road, then "straight line" is good enough.

There is an open source extension for PostGIS that can calculate road distances. It is called `pgRouting`. You will also need to create a road database - typically OpenStreetMaps is used.

Comment: Thank you. "Straight line" you mean point-based of earthdistance? Also, is it so pgRouting with openStreetMap best supported in US not in Europe relatively?

Comment: Straight Line, If we're talking about a sphere, then I meant "Great Circle Distance". Use PostGIS's functions, or use the Haversine Function to calculate the great circle distance (=shortest distance between two points on the surface of a sphere).  If anything I would expect OpenStreetMaps to have better European coverage because that is where it started, but its coverage is wide - it even includes Antarctica!

Comment: I decided to go with ST_distance function of PostGIS. I tested it with the new entries, its working quite fine. With my existing table design, now I need to make update query using ST_Distance that calculate progressive distance of existing GPS coordinates and store into distance column. Any idea how that can be achieved? Thanks